# Extract number matching a length from a string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string like so :

*I'd like to extract the postal code (5 digits) from this String*

```dart
final address = '17 Frog Road, 62000 New York';
```

Bonus would be to detect & extract the complete String after & including the postal code like so :

```dart
final extractedString = '62000 New York';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) useful.

In Dart, you can use them with the `RegExp` class.
[Here](https://www.educative.io/answers/regex-in-dart) is an introduction to Regexp in Dart.

In the code it can look like that:

```dart
const postalCodePattern = r'\b\d{5}\b';

String? extractPostalCode(String str) => RegExp(postalCodePattern).stringMatch(str);
```

To extract also anything after the match, the pattern can be modified in the following way:

```dart
const postalCodePattern = r'\b\d{5}.*';
```

That will match any symbols after the 6-digit entry.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer - what is the \b compared to @NoobN3rd 's answer ? : )

Comment: The `\b` sequence is used to mark word boundaries, which may be not only the space characters, as in the mentioned answer but also punctuation marks

Comment: Actually, the @NoobN3rd 's answer will not work if the string doesn't contain a space character after the postal code

Answer (score 2):

```
 final address = '17 Frog Road, 62000 New York';
 final extractedString = address.split(',')[1]; // 62000 New York
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular expressions. You can test your example [here](https://regexr.com/6r8jk).

Here is the Regex:

```
(\d{5})\s(.*)
```

`\d{5}` means you're looking for a 5-length number.

`\s` means a space.

`.*` means catch any character.

In Dart you can use [RegExp](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) to work with regex:

```dart
RegExp reg = RegExp(r'(\d{5})\s(.*)');
print(reg.stringMatch('17 Frog Road, 62000 New York'));
```